# Use of Header Files

Tags: c++, header

I'm new to using header files and I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong. My code compiles without any errors, but the user is never asked to input integers, and their product is never displayed. I'm using Visual Studio Community. Any ideas? Thank you!

Also is standard convention to save header files as .h and not .cpp?

In my Source File I have:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "headerp1.cpp"

int product();

int main() {
    int product();
    return 0;}
```

And in my Header File (titled as headerp1.cpp) I have:

```
#include <iostream>

int product() {

    int num1, num2, product;

    std::cout << "Please enter two integers: \n";
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2;

    product = num1 * num2;

    std::cout << "The product is " << product << "\n";
    return 0;}
```

Comment: Do *not* include a cpp file. Also to call your function you'd say `int answer = product();` because as written you never called your function, you just declared another function that happens to have the same name and return type.

Comment: Your header file is missing include guards. And besides, looks more like a source file than a header.. Also, why name a header ".cpp" rather than ".h" or ".hh"? Sure, it's just a name without any intrinsic meaning, but it's defying convention and is just plain confusing.

Comment: Yes, the convention is to name header files with ".h" (or ".hpp" or ".hxx", etc.) extensions.  The "h" stands for "header."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Until you start working with inline functions and templates do not have any code that 'does anything' in your header file. Also, by convention, header files have names ending in `.h` or `.hpp`, not `.cpp`. But this is only a convention, you can actually name them anything you like. But if you don't follow the convention, you will confuse everybody.

In your case, a header file is completely unnecessary and distracting. I'm presuming you only did that because you have an assignment that requires this.

C and C++ have a concept called a 'compilation unit'. This represents the full text of what a compiler operates on in a given invocation. A compilation unit consists of the text of a source file, and every file it includes with a `#include` directive. The `#include` directive is very simple and stupid. It simply causes that line of code (the `#include` directive itself) to be replaced with the contents of the included file.

In your case, you aren't doing anything that a knowledgeable C or C++ programmer would do because you only have one compilation unit in total in your entire program. One of your files includes the other. Having one compilation unit is perfectly acceptable. But having just one compilation unit and two files isn't, and is very strange.

In general, you need to have at least two files for a third 'header' file to even make any sense. A header file is used when you have two files that need to share some part of themselves.

In your case:

**`file1.cpp`**:

```
#include <iostream>

int product() {

    int num1, num2, product;

    std::cout << "Please enter two integers: \n";
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2;

    product = num1 * num2;

    std::cout << "The product is " << product << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

and **`file2.cpp`**:

```
int product();

int main() {
    int product();
    return 0;}
```

I removed the includes from your file containing `main` because it didn't need either of them. Now you have two files that are indeed two separate compilation units. And, in fact, in this case, no further work is needed, except to change the re-declaration of the `product` function inside main into a call to it instead (just remove the `int`). If you compile these two files and link them together into one program, it will work. No `#include` needed.

But there is still a problem here. It's not much of a problem for this small program, but for a larger program it will become a big issue. Especially if several different people are working on it.

In order to make this problem clearer, lets reorganize your program just a little:

**`product.cpp`** (lets rename this to make what's going on clearer):

```
#include <iostream>

int product() {

    int num1, num2, product;

    std::cout << "Please enter two integers: \n";
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2;

    product = num1 * num2;

    return product;
}
```

and **`main.cpp`** (and we'll rename this too):

```
#include <iostream> // Since this file now uses cout it needs this header.

int product();

int main() {
    std::cout << "The product is " << product() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Now if you compile and link this program, it still works great. But what happens if you change `product.cpp` to look like this:

```
#include <iostream>

float product() {

    int num1, num2;
    float product;

    std::cout << "Please enter two integers: \n";
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2;

    product = num1 / 3.0;
    product = product * num2;
    return product * 3;
}
```

The program will still compile, but you will get nonsense output.

The solution to this is to move shared declarations to a header file. In this case, the shared declaration is the declaration of the `product` function. So, lets do this:

**`product.hpp`**:

```
int product();
```

**`product.cpp`**:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "product.hpp"

float product() {

    int num1, num2;
    float product;

    std::cout << "Please enter two integers: \n";
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2;

    product = num1 / 3.0;
    product = product * num2;
    return product * 3;
}
```

**`main.cpp`**:

```
#include <iostream> // Since this file now uses cout it needs this header.
#include "product.hpp"

int main() {
    std::cout << "The product is " << product() << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Notice how the declaration of product (a declaration is basically just what it means, it's a line of code that says 'this thing exists') is moved out of `main.cpp` and into the `product.hpp` header file. And then we include that header file in both `main.cpp` and `product.cpp` so they both see the same declaration about the existence of `int product()`.

Unfortunately, this will no longer compile. The compiler will see the declaration of `int product()` and the definition (and declaration at the same time, some lines of code can be both) of `float product()` and sees that the same name is being declared to be two different things.

But that's good. The compiler is telling us something is wrong so we can go fix it. In this case, lets change `product.hpp` to say `float product();` instead so the two declarations agree.

Now it will compile, and you'll get sensible answers out again.

This is the purpose of header files. A header file contains a bunch of declarations of stuff so that everybody can agree one what those declarations are. Typically, you have at least two source files that both need to see a particular declaration, and then you put that declaration into a header file they both include. Usually the header file is named for the source file that defines the things it declares.

I hope this exhaustive and careful explanation helps. :-)

Answer (score 3):

Header files generally should contain function *declarations* and not function *definitions*.  I recommend a structure like this:

**headerp1.h:**

```
#ifndef HEADERP1_H
#define HEADERP1_H

/* Function declaration */
int product();

#endif  // HEADERP1_H
```

**headerp1.cpp:**

```
#include "headerp1.h"  /* Not strictly required in this case, but generally a good idea */

#include <iostream>

/* Function definition */
int product() {
    int num1, num2, product;

    std::cout << "Please enter two integers: \n";
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2;

    product = num1 * num2;

    std::cout << "The product is " << product << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

**main.cpp:**

```
#include "headerp1.h"

int main() {
    /* Function invocation */
    product();
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Thanks.  Fixed include guard identifier.

Answer (score 1):

In header files you make a function declaration and you implement it in the source file. Take a look at [this](http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10627/).

Your code should look like this:

Source file: `src.cpp`

```
#include "header.h"

int main() 
{
    product();
    return 0;
}

int product() 
{
    int num1, num2, product;

    std::cout << "Please enter two integers: \n";
    std::cin >> num1 >> num2;

    product = num1 * num2;

    std::cout << "The product is " << product << "\n";
    return 0;
}
```

Header file: `header.h`

```
#include <iostream>

int product();
```

Comment: This is a rather silly use of a header. After all, `src.cpp` only needs a forward declaration of `product`. The point of a header is to declare things that are defined in **some other** file. Put the definition of `product` into a separate source file and the header becomes useful.

Comment: I just corrected his code to make it useful, in order for him to see how it should be to make it work. I agree that it doesn't too much sense this way.